# XPath how to find second element with CSS class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath

I have this html:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-power-select-trigger ember-power-select-trigger-2568211667 category-select t-ticket-category-select-trigger">
   Building
</div>

<div tabindex="0" class="ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-power-select-trigger ember-power-select-trigger-6101225577 category-select t-ticket-category-select-trigger">
  Warehouse
</div>
```

I would like to access the text in the **2nd** div that has the same CSS class name, but am not sure how to access it.

I have some XPath code like this, but this doesn't work:

```
//*[contains(@class, 't-ticket-category-select-trigger')]
```

Comment: What environment are you working in? In you're working in Python, you might want to check out the `cssselect` library, which converts CSS selectors to Xpath (https://github.com/SimonSapin/cssselect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access it *by index* (indexing starts with 1 in XPath):

```
(//*[contains(@class, 't-ticket-category-select-trigger')])[2]
```

Or, if it is the *last* one:

```
(//*[contains(@class, 't-ticket-category-select-trigger')])[last()]
```

Comment: Alecxe, I added all CSS classes for these `divs` to my question.  I tried your answer, but can't get it to work.  Is the syntax different if there are other CSS classes in the DOM element?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AronYsidoro okay, thanks, quick check - would this work: `(//*[contains(@class, 't-ticket-category-select-trigger')])[2]` (note the parenthesis)?